# Checking if array value exists in a PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array 
         ( [id] => 1 
           [name] => Jonah 
           [points] => 27 )
        [1] => Array 
         ( [id] => 2 
           [name] => Mark 
           [points] => 34 )
      )
```

I'm currently using a `foreach` loop to extract the values from the array:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $sub)
{
    ...
}
```

But I was wondering how do I see whether a value within the array already exists.

So for example if I wanted to add another set to the array, but the id is `1` (so the person is Jonah) and their score is 5, can I add the 5 to the already created array value in `id 0` instead of creating a new array value?

So after the loop has finished the array will look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array 
         ( [id] => 1 
           [name] => Jonah 
           [points] => 32 )
        [1] => Array 
         ( [id] => 2 
           [name] => Mark 
           [points] => 34 )
      )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about looping over your array, checking for each item if it's `id` is the one you're looking for ?

```
$found = false;
foreach ($your_array as $key => $data) {
    if ($data['id'] == $the_id_youre_lloking_for) {
        // The item has been found => add the new points to the existing ones
        $data['points'] += $the_number_of_points;
        $found = true;
        break; // no need to loop anymore, as we have found the item => exit the loop
    }
}

if ($found === false) {
    // The id you were looking for has not been found, 
    // which means the corresponding item is not already present in your array
    // => Add a new item to the array
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Pascal, just one question - If I didn't know the id of the array, is there a way to go through all the arrays and check that it matches (e.g `[id] == 2` or `[name] == Mark `)?

Comment: You'd just have to change the condition, to reflect what you want ; it would the become something like `if ($data['id'] == $the_id_youre_lloking_for || $data['name'] == $the_name_youre_looking_for)`

Answer (score 1):

you can first store the array with index equal to the id.
for example :

```
 $arr =Array ( [0] => Array 
     ( [id] => 1 
       [name] => Jonah 
       [points] => 27 )
    [1] => Array 
     ( [id] => 2 
       [name] => Mark 
       [points] => 34 )
  );
 $new = array();
 foreach($arr as $value){
    $new[$value['id']] = $value; 
 }

//So now you can check the array $new for if the key exists already 
if(array_key_exists(1, $new)){
    $new[1]['points'] = 32;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is answered, I wanted to post my answer. Might come handy to future viewers. You can create new array from this array with filter then from there you can check if value exist on that array or not. You can follow below code. [Sample](https://eval.in/502267)

```
$arr = array(
        0 =>array(
                "id"=> 1,
                "name"=> "Bangladesh",
                "action"=> "27"
            ),
         1 =>array(
                "id"=> 2,
                "name"=> "Entertainment",
                "action"=> "34"
                 )
        );

     $new = array();
     foreach($arr as $value){
        $new[$value['id']] = $value; 
     }


    if(array_key_exists(1, $new)){
        echo $new[1]['id'];
    }
    else {
      echo "aaa";
    }
    //print_r($new);
```