# php save array of values

Tags: php, session

I need to save last 10 viewed products in `$_SESSION`, so I try to use code below, but in this case `$_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList']` keeps only last `$product`

```
$title = $node->title;
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; 
$img = $node->uc_product_image['und'][0]['filename'];
$product = array('title' => $title, 'url' => $url, 'img' => $img);

if (!isset($_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'])) {
  $_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'] = $product;
} else {
  $_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'] = $product;
}
```

How to save last 10 products?

Comment: Add to `$_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'][]` so you can access `$_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'][0], $_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'][1],...$_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'][9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$title = $node->title;
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; 
$img = $node->uc_product_image['und'][0]['filename'];
$product = array('title' => $title, 'url' => $url, 'img' => $img);

if (!isset($_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'])) {
    // If the SESSION parameter does not exists, we create it as an array
    $products = array($product);
} else {
    // Else, we add the product in it
    $products = $_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'];
    $products[] = $product;
    // We check if the array has more than 10 rows
    if(count($products) > 10){
        // If that's the case, we remove the first line in it to keep 10 rows in it
        array_shift($products);
    }
}

$_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'] = $products;
```

If you want to check if the product is already in the array, check this solution: [PHP: Check if value and key exist in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990855/php-check-if-value-and-key-exist-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: I guess line `$_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'] = $products;` can be placed after `if...else` (I see it two times here). Or not?

Comment: After some thinking I actually don't understand why `$_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'] = $products;` placed after `if...else` works, because array `$products` is initialized inside `if...else` and should be undefinied outside, shouldn't it?

Comment: Hi Heidel, in any case $products will be defined, in the if or in the else statement. No need to declare it outside.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your array in json format with `json_encode()` function and save it in your session. Or you can even use php `serialize`, but i personally prefer json becouse object serialization may lead to some vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$title = $node->title;
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; 
$img = $node->uc_product_image['und'][0]['filename'];
$product = array('title' => $title, 'url' => $url, 'img' => $img);

if (!isset($_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'])) {
$_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'][] = $product;
} else {
$_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'][] = $product;
}
```

Comment: How can I add check here to save in `$_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList']` only unique products and not save the same product a few times?

Comment: if (in_array(product['title'],$_SESSION['lastViewedProductsList'][])) {
}

Comment: check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240251/checking-if-array-value-exists-in-a-php-multidimensional-array